# Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: git, github, git-shell

I'm using GitHub desktop and I have no problem until I try to make a new pull request or sync a branch. 
When I write `git stage` I receive:

> Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

But I have the git folder in the repository. I tried to clone again the repository.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: When running `git stage`, are you in the right folder? Use `pwd` to find out.

Comment: Are you running git commands from within the `.git` directory? Usually you're not supposed to do that.

Comment: Yes I am in te right folder. Github desktop give an error when I try to upload new changes.

Comment: How can I be sure thar I am running git commands from wirhin the .git directory?

Comment: just use `cd ..` and then run the above command

Answer (score 0):

You should not run git commands in the `.git` directory. Instead, you must run them in the parent directory of the `.git` directory.